# store data of all the checked rows bootstrap table in an array

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table in my reactJS application. To populate the table, I call an api and map the response to this table's rows. It looks like this

```
 <TableBody
                    showRowHover={true}
                    deselectOnClickaway={false}>
                    {
                        this.state.MediaFiles.map((item,i)=> (
                            <TableRow
                                key={i}
                                className={`table-item-${i}`}
                                selected={this.props.selectedRows.includes(i)}>
                                <TableRowColumn className='td-filename'>
                                    <div className='item-file-details'>
                                        <div className='file-image' style={{backgroundImage: `url('${item.poster.list_thumbnail}')`}}/>
                                        <div className='details'>
                                            <p className='detail-name'> {item.title} </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-channel">Zee</p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                                <TableRowColumn>
                                    <p className="file-duration">Movie </p>
                                </TableRowColumn>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))
                    }
                </TableBody>
```

I want to save the `{item.title}` of each file I check in the `table` in an `array`. `Id checkbox` is checked then the `{item.title}` of that `row` or item should get appended to the `array`. When I uncheck it, data should get removed from array. My main problem is to how to get `{item.tiltle}` data out. If there any `onChecked` and `onUnchecked` kind of method for bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer comes a little bit late ;)

The "onChecked" and "onUnchecked" method is as follows:

```
$table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table' , function (e, row, $row, colname) {
    //  do something
    getIdSelections($table)
    
});
```

In case you click the "all" checkbox, then this will cover all events

```
$table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' + 'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table', function (e, row, $row, colname) {
    //  do something
    getIdSelections($table)
    
});
```

The parameter "row" will contain all fields of the selected row and you can access the data like **"row.title".**

Here is a function, that collect all id`s and return it as comma separated string

```
function getIdSelections($table) {
//  collect all table rows which tick box is marked for action and return an array
try {
    return $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
        return row['colname_of_the_id_column'];
    });
} catch (e) {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name + ": " + e.message, e);
    }
}
```

here you will find all events
[bootstrap table events](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/)